# Pythonic Way to Handle Non-Existant Python Dict Keys

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm using an API that returns a JSON object that I easily convert to a dict. We'll call the converted JSON-to-dict object, JSON_API_ITEM.

However, sometimes the JSON_API_ITEM doesn't have certain fields (like url for example). Instead of setting that field to None, the field simply isn't present so when I make an assignment:

```
url = JSON_API_ITEM['url']
```

My program throws an exception. I thought of using a for loop across dict.keys() or putting everything in a try or if block, but that will make my code extremely ugly.

What is the pythonic way to handle something like this?

Comment: Wait, you get an exception when *assigning* to a missing field? Dicts shouldn't do that.

Comment: this does not give an exception; you get an exception if `my_item` is None

Comment: @user2357112 Maybe his key is unhashable, and the example provided is incorrect here.

Comment: I'm still confused about your question. Did you mean to ask about getting dict values originally? If so, why did you accept the first answer? According to the official docs, EAFP is more Pythonic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [get](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method.

```
my_item.get('url',None) # None is default in case url key does not exist.
```

EDIT:

I undelete my answer as, after OP's edit, its clear that the issue is about getting value from a dict, not about assignment.

Comment: @Cilyan OP edited the question, and it seems its about get now, not about assignment.

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted, thank you. For those of you with nested dictionaries just make sure to put the entire path except for the last field before the .get(). For example: Use url = my_item['company'].get('name', None) instead of url = my_item.get(['company']['name'], None)

Comment: @Marcin: Lucky you :) Removing the comment.

Comment: @uspowpow: No, that's not how Python syntax works. That would attempt to use `'name'` as an index into the 1-element list `['company']`. You'd want `my_item.get('company', {}).get('name', None)`.

Answer (score 3):

Although `.get()` works and is the shortest (I think) way to do this, a more Pythonic way would be [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) or "Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission". That means that a try/except block is how you're supposed to do it:

```
try:
    url = my_item['url']
except KeyError e:
    url = None
```

I'm assuming here that you meant to write `url = my_item['url']`, not `my_item['url'] = url`

I see the answer about [`.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) was removed. I'll explain it, also.

You can use `url = my_item.get('url',None)`; the second argument to `dict.get()` is a default value. It actually defaults to `None`, though, so you can just write `utl = my_item.get('url')`

Comment: I removed my answer as the question is about assignment, and not about getting value, as pointed out by @Cilyan.

Comment: @Marcin Huh...I guess you're right; OP specifically mentions assignment. That's weird. S/he says "[his/her] program throws an exception", which it clearly does not.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was feeling funny when I wrote the OP and you guys quickly caught it, I was talking about getting the value. Sorry for the poor OP and thanks for the help, update to come in a few minutes on the results.

Comment: Also thanks for the this post in regards to assignment, that'll help me the rest of my career!

Comment: @KSFT I think this is is mistake: `url = my_item('url',None)`. You forgot the `get` part.

Answer (score 0):

As your question has changed, this answer is out-of-scope but still posting in case someone needs to *assign* to maybe non-existent keys, instead of just needing *access*.

This is done using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) instead of a dict in the loaded JSON. The convertion is done using the `object_hook`. This hook is called whenever a JSON object is scanned (which usually results in a dict in Python). In the following example, the `default_factory` simply returns `None`, but you can place something more interesting for your purpose if you want (an empty dict, for example, so that chained `getitem` calls do not fail).

```
samplejson = """
{
    "menu": {
        "id": "file",
        "value": "File",
        "popup": {
            "menuitem": [
                { "value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()" },
                { "value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()" },
                { "value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()" }
            ]
        }
    }
}
"""

jsobject = json.loads(
    samplejson,
    object_hook=lambda obj: collections.defaultdict(lambda:None, **obj)
)

print(jsobject["menu"]["id"])
print(jsobject["menu"]["tooltip"])
jsobject["menu"]["tooltip"] = "File menu"
jsobject["menu"]["accel"] = "Alt+F"
print(jsobject["menu"]["accel"])
print(jsobject["menu"]["tooltip"])

#Output:
#file
#None
#Alt+F
#File menu
```